# Asynchronous Load ckeditor in angular using lazyload service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using lazy loading implementation to make async call to some js files which are not required initially. I am facing issue is with ckeditor. I am using [angular ckeditor](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor), so both ckeditor.js and angular.ckeditor.js are loaded using the lazyload service. both js are being resolved and added correctly. I have also injected the required module but ckeditor is not being populated. is there any way to regenerate ckeditor after js files are loaded? any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

I have following lazy load service to async load ckeditor and angular.ckeditor.js.

```js
.service('lazyLoad', ['$document', '$q', '$timeout', function ($document, $q, $timeout) {

    function loader(createElement) {
        var promises = {};

        return function (url) {
            if (typeof promises[url] === 'undefined') {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var element = createElement(url);

                element.onload = element.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(e);
                    });
                };
                element.onerror = function (e) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        deferred.reject(e);
                    });
                };

                promises[url] = deferred.promise;
            }

            return promises[url];
        };
    }


    this.loadScript = loader(function (src) {
        var script = $document[0].createElement('script');

        script.src = src;

        $document[0].body.appendChild(script);
        return script;
    });

}])
```

And this is the service to the angular.ckeditor.js and ckeditor.js. Pushing the required 'ckeditor' module manually.

```js
.service('ckeditorService', function($window, $q, lazyLoad) {
    this.CKEDITOR = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (typeof $window.CKEDITOR === "undefined") {
            lazyLoad.loadScript('bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js').then(function() {
                lazyLoad.loadScript('bower_components/angular-ckeditor/angular-ckeditor.js').then(function() {
                    var app = angular.module('mainModule');
                    app.requires.push('ckeditor');
                    console.log('success loading : bower_components/angular-ckeditor/angular-ckeditor.js');

                    deferred.resolve($window.CKEDITOR);
                }).catch(function() {
                    console.log('Error loading : bower_components/angular-ckeditor/angular-ckeditor.js');
                    deferred.resolve($window.CKEDITOR);
                });

                //deferred.resolve($window.CKEDITOR);
            }).catch(function() {
                console.log('Error loading : bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
                deferred.resolve($window.CKEDITOR);
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve($window.CKEDITOR);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };

});
```

This is controller which calls the service.

```js
.controller('productController', function (ckeditorService) {

     ckeditorService.CKEDITOR().then(function (CKEDITOR) {
       console.log('ckeditor loaded');
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ngIf directive (documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)). When ckeditor is loaded it will recreate the portion of the DOM for the directive;

Comment: I have tried this but still no luck, Actually I am getting the instance in console, but CKEDITOR is not being rendered. Any methods to re render CKEDITOR?